# Where to get world-map images for use in webglearth

Tags: data, tiles, wgs84, web-mercator, world-imagery

I am using webglearth for a 3D earth globe. 
I already bought MapTiler, from the same makers.

Now I am struggling with finding different world-map-images with the right projection. I need either WGS 84 or Web-Mercator. I would also buy them.

So is there any sites that specialized in that and I'm just not finding?

Or how would any of you get customized / differently themed world-map-images for use as a texture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may check http://vterrain.org/Imagery/WholeEarth/ for links to satellite imagery, or http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/ for raster images. These images can be tweaked in Photoshop to get your own look&feel and rendered with MapTiler into tiles - check http://examples.webglearth.com/#customtiles and esp. http://www.maptiler.com/how-to/3d-online-globe/ for tutorials.

If you want to get more high-res satellite data for certain regions in the world, then google "landsat", otherwise, go for the aerial photos available as opendata (such as the US "naip" data) or imagery from commercial providers like DigitalGlobe.

If you want to work on styling the vector data with custom colors etc, then TileMill and NaturalEarthData vector data may be of help - or the MapBox Studio (online or Classic).

We plan to make a section at http://www.maptiler.com/ with links to freely downloadable open-data as well - so check this web in near future too...